# wmware p2v convertor failed with "Network is unreachable Network error"

Tags: linux, ssh, vmware-esxi

I want to convert Ubuntu physical to Esxi vm 
ssh connection to physical OS is OK on my network.
vmware convertor stops converting at 3% with

> "Network is unreachable Network error. Host x.x.x.x key can't be retrieved. (return code 2)"

I suspected there is an issue between ESXI server and Ubuntu so I enabled ssh on ESXI.I logged in ESXI
I can Ping ubuntu , **but I can not connect ssh to ubuntu on ESXI(time out)** 
I can fetch html content from ubuntu using wget on ESXI ,
I can connect ssh on ESXI itself by "ssh root@127.0.0.1"
**I can not connect ssh on other linux based systems presented in my network on ESXI host**
I installed a test vm (windows server) on esxi I can connect ssh whithout any problem
all hosts are allowed to connect in my physical ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

problem is resolved !
the issue was the destination host ip address, my source is located on another subnet , I should set router IP address on destination network adapter